# Left side menu with scroll bar when click on menu link then scroll bar move its not show scroll bar near to the clicked menu

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

Left side menu with scroll bar when click on menu link then scroll bar move not show scroll bar near to the clicked menu.
As u can see in [w3schools](http://www.w3school.com) site when clicked  on side menu then scroll bar again comes on its same position on which menu we have clicked. I want same work as show by me a menu list in which  tag with list item

I have used scroll bar class of .scroll_text_menu 
now my question is when I clicked on scroll bar menu than its goes upper side not leaves near clicked menu

**Code:**

```css
.scroll_text_menu {
  height: 640px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  line-height: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu ">
  <div class="menu_section">
    <h3><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>dashboard">Dashboard</a></h3>
    <?php
                                        $userType = $this->session->userData('userType');
                                        ?>
      <ul class="nav side-menu scroll_text_menu">
        <?php if ($userType == 1) { ?>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>account"><i class="fa fa-bank"></i> Account Management </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Training_program_exercise"><i class="fa fa-file-text" ></i> Training Program</a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if (in_array($userType, array("1", "2"))) { ?>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>coach"><i class="fa fa-user-md" style="font-size:19px"></i> Coach Management </a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>



        <?php if (in_array($userType, array("1", "2", "3"))) { ?>

        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Athlete1"><i class="fa fa-user" ></i> Athlete Management </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>team"><i class="fa fa-users"  style="font-size: 17px;"></i> Team Management </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/exercise_parent_type"><i class="fa fa-houzz"  style="font-size:20px"></i> Exercise Parent Type</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/exercise_type"><i class="fa fa-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></i> Exercise Types</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Athlete_exercise"><i class="fa fa-wheelchair-alt"></i> Exercise </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/Exercise_sets"><i class="fa fa-columns" aria-hidden="true"></i> Exercise Sets</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>training"><i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size: 17px"></i> Training Plan </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/Planprograms"><i class="fa fa-map-o" style="font-size: 17px"></i> Programs Plans</a>
        </li>



        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/privacyPolicySelect"><i class="fa fa-lock" ></i> Privacy Policy</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/selectQquestion"><i  class="fa fa-question-circle-o"  aria-hidden="true" ></i><span > Questionnaire</span></a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/answers"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> User Answer</a>
        </li>


        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>School"><i class="fa fa-building-o" ></i> School</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/Position_title"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o" aria-hidden="true"  ></i> Position Title</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/Sports"><i class="fa fa-futbol-o" ></i> Sports</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index/Language"><i class="fa fa-language"></i> Languages</a>
        </li>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)